# jqPlot to uishield options and properties mapping

Tags: jqplot

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that currently uses jqPlot to draw charts (mostly line graphs).

I'm researching moving to Shield UI, so was wondering if anyone has done this before and, if so, if you have any documentation that shows how to map jqPlot charting options to Shield UIoptions. I'm trying to save a little time not having to dig through all the documentation. Thanks.